# load continuously updating data in a csv file using setInterval and clearInterval in js

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'i' before initialization` with below code.

I am completely new to js and i know this is not the best way to achieve what I am trying.

So the file.csv is getting updated as the js is running, i need to load new data until end of row of the file which is 190 is reached.

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
            fetch('./file.csv')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(transform);
            function transform(str) {
                console.log(str)
                var data = Papa.parse(str , { header: true, dynamicTyping: true, skipEmptyLines: true }).data;
                console.log(data);
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    console.log("Starting the main function")
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    let retured_data = function_A(data, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    let i = retured_data.i;
                    let b = retured_data.blue;
                    let g = retured_data.green;
                    let y = retured_data.yellow;
                    let a = retured_data.amber;
                    let r = retured_data.red;
                    console.log("Current Values of i, b, g, y, a, r" + i + " " + b + " " + g + " " + y + " " + a + " " + r)
                    var interval_next = window.setInterval(function () {
                        console.log("Inside Second Loop Values of i, b, g, y, a, r" + i + " " + b + " " + g + " " + y + " " + a + " " + r)
                        let retured_data = function_A(data, i, b, g, y, a, r);
                        let i = retured_data.i;
                        let b = retured_data.blue;
                        let g = retured_data.green;
                        let y = retured_data.yellow;
                        let a = retured_data.amber;
                        let r = retured_data.red;
                        if (data.length == 190) {
                            console.log("Complete Data Loaded")
                            clearInterval(interval_next);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
```

So the logic i have created here is keep trying to check for data in file.csv every "1000" if data>length meaning data is there, function_A is called with data,i,b,g,y,a,r variables which are incremented in that function with each row processed in data, then the function_A returns these values, which i am again processing after "2000" msec with new values returned from function_A until end of row is reached.

Below is the function_A

```
function function_A(data, i, b, g, y, a, r) {
    var data = data;
    var i = i;
    var blue = b;
    var green = g;
    var yellow = y;
    var amber = a;
    var red = r;
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.length)
    var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
        console.log(data[i]);
        console.log("Value of i: " + i)
        var row = data[i];
        if (row.Colour == "Blue") {
            blue++;
        } else if (row.Colour == "Green") {
            green++;
        } else if (row.Colour == "Yellow") {
            yellow++;
        } else if (row.Colour == "Amber") {
            amber++;
        } else if (row.Colour == "Red") {
            red++;
        } else {
            pass
        }
        i++;
        var total = document.getElementById('total_count');
        total.innerHTML = i;
        total.innerHTML += '<br><span style="font-size: 15px;">Total No Of Assets Impacted</span>';
        bar_chart(blue, green, yellow, amber, red);
        pie_chart(blue, green, yellow, amber, red);
        console.log("Value of i after end of iteration: " + i)
        console.log("Blue: " + blue + " Green: " + green + " Yellow: " + yellow + " Amber: " + amber + " Red: " + red)
        if (i == data.length) {
            console.log("I am in if loop")
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 2000);
    return { i, blue, green, yellow, amber, red };
}
```

Another strange thing i observed is, I thought the sequence of operations would be first to execute `let retured_data = function_A(data, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` , meaning all steps in function_A and then i can use it to assign values, However the sequence I see is it does is as below:

```
console.log(str) (from main code)
console.log(data) (from main code)
console.log("Starting the main function") (from main code)
console.log(data) (from function_A)
console.log(data.length) (from function_A)
console.log("Current Values of i, b, g, y, a, r" + i + " " + b + " " + g + " " + y + " " + a + " " + r) (from main code)
console.log(data[i]); (from function_A)
console.log("Value of i: " + i) (from function_A)
console.log("Value of i after end of iteration: " + i) (from function_A)
console.log("Blue: " + blue + " Green: " + green + " Yellow: " + yellow + " Amber: " + amber + " Red: " + red) (from function_A)
```

Comment: which line of code produces the error? - oh, I see, you `let retured_data = function_A(data, i, b, g, y, a, r);` and then `let i =` etc - remove the `let` for those next few lines, since you want the previous values in that call to `function_A` they will need to be "stored" outside of the setInterval anyway

Comment: Thanks @Bravo for the response, are you saying "let" is the issue? Or setting this outside setInterval? How would i set the values outside setInterval?

Comment: using let ... don't use let inside, since you want to use the outer variables

Comment: also, not sure how `data.length` would change inside the inner interval ... so, unless it's 190 when you first enter the inner interval, you'll be stuck there forever - also `var data = data;` etc is redundant, don't need to do that

Comment: another issue is ... you `return { i, blue, green, yellow, amber, red };` immediately, before any of the code in the setInterval has run - so you're basically returning exactly what you received

Comment: Thanks @Bravo i made the changes, all let are replaced with var, and removed redundant assignation, also you are right that return is returning values which was assigned so i have put the return right before clearInterval of function_A. Anything else?

Comment: `all let are replaced with var` which isn't anything I said to do - remove let for i,r,etc inside the interval is what I said, not replace let with var

Comment: `i have put the return right before clearInterval` which won't help, since now you aren't going to return a thing from `function_A`

Comment: and you still haven't addressed the fact that your inner interval will run forever, or once at most - depending on the length of data

Comment: Now I am getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'i')`  Also in function_A even after i == data.length it said the return statement as undefined i guess because it does print "I am in if loop" but does run the whole code for i =9. the idea for inner interval to run after every 2 sec is to check if new data has come in until data.length = 190 which is the final row the file is expected to have

Comment: no idea what your code looks like since you made changes that nobody suggested - see if [this code](https://pastebin.com/FdnQ8AWj) works for you

Comment: Thanks @Bravo, i tried the code, it gave processLine() not defined for the second one. I just pasted my [entire code](https://pastebin.com/t8Z8PncB) with your code in it.

Comment: the second what? there's a typo ... `const proccessLine` should be `const processLine`

Comment: @Bravo that's really a silly mistake, i apologise, But I am getting below error now, it does display first row in map, but doesn't update the total_count, bar and pie charts `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at processLine ((index):219:37)
    at (index):231:24
    at transform ((index):346:20)
    at fn ((index):352:33)`

Comment: Perhaps move the script as the last thing before `</body>` ... though, just move `const total = document.getElementById('total_count');` to where it was in your code, just before `total.innerHTML =` etc - I moved it out of habit :p

Comment: Yeah that did solve the problem but after initial 9 rows which it displayed perfectly it gave below error and didn't process the next lines which were updated in the file. `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Latitude')
    at processLine ((index):182:38)
    at (index):231:24
    at transform ((index):346:20)
    at fn ((index):352:33)`

Comment: that would suggest `i` is greater than `data.length - 1` - just add some debugging console.logs around there to see what is happening (most interested in  `data.length` and `i`  at the top of `processLine` )